# My gameobjects in unity lose their quality and become blurry in play mode, but are very high quality in the scene view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, as the title says I have a problem with the quality/resolution in my game, but all the the object in my game are very high quality in the inspector.

Just to give some extra information, the game I am making is a 2d mobile game. And you can see the inspector settings of a gameobject in an image below.[image]

INSPECTOR SETTINGS OF ONE GAMEOBJECT (PLAYER):
[image]

Comment: What target machine and resolution are you developing for?

Comment: I think this might just be caused by the game view rendering at a low resolution. Try setting the aspect ratio to a high fixed resolution like 1080x1920 and see if the problem persists.

Comment: You have the scale set to 6.3x in the game view.  Change the scale back to 1x

Comment: How can I change the aspect ratio to a higher resolution?

Comment: In the GameView, on the right, towards the top of the screen there is a drop-down that let's you choose your aspect ratio and resolution.  Currently you have "18:9" picked.  Pick a real resolution and aspect ratio.  If there is none, create one.  Also, as @hijinxbassist mentioned, you're really zoomed-in.  This will give you a false view of what it will look like on your target device.

Comment: Check camera Anti Aliasing.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I changed the resolution to 900x1800. And yes I saw what @hijinxbassist mentioned, but the reason I zoomed in, was so that you could see the difference between the scene- and gameview better. But a problem that I have now is that my game is much slower than normal. On another note, my scale tool in the inspector is automatically set to 0.23x, is this normal?